# Remove non-numerics from filename/string

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets suppose I have a bulk of files that need to be formatted to be better accessible by an application.

Currently a file name may look like this:

```
035 - Springfield, MA.pdf
```

The way my application references an object is by that id the file is prefixed with, so I started embarking on bulk renaming below:

```
def rename(dir, pattern):
    import glob, os
    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        print(title)
        os.rename(pathAndFilename, 
            os.path.join(dir, % title + ext))
```

Now I can pass the following command to rename all my maps:

```
import scripts as a    
a.rename(r'c:\tools\storeMaps', r'*.pdf')
```

I want the output of the filenames to solely be the ID + map, so I know I can join `map` fairly easily, but I'm having some trouble efficiently removing all non-numerics from the file name.

Comment: I feel like you would be better off using regex for this. Retrieve the file name, use regex to extract and replace the filename then rename the file with the number (id only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the joys of `re` to solve this.

```
def rename(dir, pattern):
    import glob, os, re
    for pathAndFilename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(dir, pattern)):
        title, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pathAndFilename))
        print(title)
        new_title = re.sub("\D", "", title)
        os.rename(pathAndFilename, 
            os.path.join(dir, new_title + ext))
```

`new_title = re.sub("\D", "", title)` will remove any non-digits from `title`.